How can I fill the outline of a quarter ellipsoid with faces?
How can I fill in the shape by following these edges?


why don't you just take the "inner" ring and use extrude along normals?

Maybe start from a 1/8th of a UVsphere and move some vertices around ? If you need to fill the space with a round shape, I don't think there is a quick or easy method.

Extrude and snap to find the center (if you don't already have).
Use Shift+S > Cursor to Selected to place the 3D Cursor there, then delete the center vertex.

Add a dense sphere and scale it so to fit exactly (use snap functions, especially using B key to align vertex to vertex).
Then enable Face snap with Face Project individual elements on.

Start building topology as desired.

When finished, select all newly created vertices, press Ctrl+G > Assign to New Group.

Add a Shrinkwrap Modifier, limited to the new Vertex Group, targeting the sphere.
Right click and choose Smooth Vertices (smoothing 1.0, repeat many times).

Apply the Shrinkwrap Modifier (Ctrl+A on the modifier).


Press Shift+C to position 3D Cursor at World Origin. Make sure you change the Transform Pivot Point to 3D Cursor.

Then select the lower Edge Loop, press Shift+D to duplicate, S then Shift+Z to scale on the XY plane and immediately press B for vertex snapping and click the first vertex of the Edge Loop and the next higher vertex of your shape as shown below to make sure the scale snaps right below the upper vertex. Then press G then B and select the same vertices again to snap the duplicated Edge Loop to the upper vertex.

Repeat the procedure going upwards until you end up with something like this:

Then add a Geometry Nodes modifier and add a Convex Hull node. You can Apply this modifier and then tab into Edit Mode and press A to select all vertices and then press Ctrl+F > Tris to Quads.

